# How can I create hollow pipework?

Tags: mesh, unity

I'm trying to create a length of pipe with includes straight and curved lengths.

I'm wanting to create a mesh so I can import it into unity, add a mesh collider and run fluid through it.

Does anyone know the best way to approach this?

Comment: For modelling pipes, bezier curves are recommended: see the "bevel object" of curves, converting curves to meshes, and the curve modifier. Using it as a collision object for real time fluid simulations in Unity sounds like a separate problem for the Unity forums.

Comment: As well as curve objects, enable the Add Mesh Extra Objects addon. It adds *Mechanical->Pipe Joints* to the add mesh object menu which has several variations of joints.

Answer (score 2):

To model it I would add a cylinder, tab for edit mode, remove the caps of the cylinder.

Then in add and apply a **solidify** modifier.

You possibly should also create a simplified pipe with smaller amount of vertices to work as a collision mesh for a  mesh collider, because higher poly pipe might require quite a bit of collision calculations.